# Payment issue in Authorize.Net - E00027 "Charge Credit card: Invalid response"

Tags: authorize.net

Whenever we are doing the payment from the local machine with the API call payment is done even if there are decimal values like $123.09. But whenever we are trying to do the payment using the live code, however, there is an error when the value is $123.09. It accepts payments having whole value like $100.00 so what can be the issue?

I expect output transaction successful, but the actual output is

> error E00027 "Charge Credit card: Invalid response"

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search returns the following information for [error code E00027](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCodes.html?code=E00027):

> **CODE**: E00027
>
> **EXPLANATION**: The transaction was unsuccessful.
>
> **DESCRIPTION**: An approval was not returned for the transaction.
>
> **INTEGRATION SUGGESTIONS**: This error may occur for merchants on the HSBC or FDI Australia processors when setting validationMode to
>   liveMode as these processors do not support authorization reversals.
>   We recommend HSBC and FDI Australia merchants set validationMode to
>   testMode instead.
>
> **OTHER SUGGESTIONS**: For more information, check the errorCode field in the response.

A quick search also indicates you are using [sample code provided by Authorize.Net](https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/) as that is the only way to generate this exact error message.

So here is some troubleshooting steps you can take:

- If you are using HSBC or FDI Australia processors make sure liveMode is set to `testMode`.
- Make sure you are not accidentally using your developer account or have your account set to test mode.
- Make sure you are not in test mode and triggering a [specific testing response](https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/testing_guide/).
- Make sure you are using the correct account credentials (api login and transaction key).
- Make sure you are using TLS 1.2 (e.g. make sure you are not using TLS 1.0 or 1.1).
- If testing using a live account make sure the credit card is valid.